# Qt 4.8.2 QWebView getting Content-type missing in HTTP POST, defaulting to application/octet-stream

Tags: c++, qt, qwebview

i have popup window that is opened from web page ( its paypal popup) 
i capture it and then i try to fix this error as the document suggesting here http://qt-project.org/doc/note_revisions/84/125/view
but still im getting this error 
here is my QWebView class

```
class WebView : public QWebView
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    WebView()
    {
        connect( this->page()->networkAccessManager(),
             SIGNAL(sslErrors(QNetworkReply*, const QList<QSslError> & )),
             this,
             SLOT(sslErrorHandler(QNetworkReply*, const QList<QSslError> & )));
    }

private slots:
    void sslErrorHandler( QNetworkReply *reply, const QList<QSslError> &errors)
    {
        qDebug() << "sslErrorHandler:";
        foreach (QSslError err, errors)
          qDebug() << "ssl error: " << err;

        reply->ignoreSslErrors();
    }

protected:
    QWebView *createWindow(QWebPage::WebWindowType type)
    {
        QWebView *webview = new QWebView;

        QUrl tmpUrl = webview->url(); 
        QNetworkRequest request(tmpUrl);
        //request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader,QVariant("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
        request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader,"application/octet-stream");

        //webview->show();
        webview->load(request,QNetworkAccessManager::PostOperation);
        return webview;
    }
};
```

what im doing wrong here ?

Comment: I'm confused, why are you doing a post operation instead of a get?  Or if I'm mistaken, what exactly are you trying to post to the site?

Comment: this is invoked when i popup window from my page ...

Comment: You shouldn't be creating a request in `createWindow`. If the current page tries to open a new window, this function will be called and the new url should automatically be loaded in the new window. What error do you get when there is only `QWebView *webview = new QWebView; webview->show(); return webview;` in `createWindow()`  ?

Comment: i dont get any error only the massage as in the question